# Display value in input field from multiple select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select name="place_have" class="form-control" multiple>
    <option value="locker">locker</option>
    <option value="storage">storage</option>
    <option value="bathroom">bathroom</option>
    <option value="food">food</option>
    <option value="parking">parking</option>
    <option value="play ground">play ground</option>
    <option value="smoking room">smoking room</option>
</select>
```

Values selected above should display in another input text field below. Any help?

Comment: If you need an answer in jquery code then please tag your question with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *jQuery*:

```js
$("select[name='place_have']").change(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("input#optionOutput").val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="place_have" class="form-control" multiple>
  <option value="locker">locker</option>
  <option value="storage">storage</option>
  <option value="bathroom">bathroom</option>
  <option value="food">food</option>
  <option value="parking">parking</option>
  <option value="play ground">play ground</option>
  <option value="smoking room">smoking room</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="optionOutput">
```